# Declare a global variable and set it inside for-each in XSLT in WSO2

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have declared a global variable and trying to set the value inside for-each. Later I want to access that variable outside the for-each. I am sure that the value will be set only once inside iteration. Below is the code I have tried in XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="$CALL_FROM = 'CREATE_CUSTOMER'">
        <customerData xmlns="">
                <xsl:variable name="UPDATE_FLAG"/>
                <ContactInfo>
                            <xsl:if test="$FLAG = 'True'">
                                <xsl:for-each select="/jsonObject/data">
                                    <xsl:variable name="UPDATE_REQUIRED">
                                        <xsl:if test="id != $CUSTOMER_ID">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:variable>
                                    <xsl:variable name="UPDATE_FLAG" select="$UPDATE_REQUIRED"/>
                                    <Address>
                                        <AddressLine1>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="address1"/>
                                        </AddressLine1>
                                        <AddressLine2>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="address2"/>
                                        </AddressLine2>
                                        <Country>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
                                        </Country>
                                        <Code>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
                                        </Code>
                                    </Address>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:if>
                </ContactInfo>
                    <UpdateRequiredFlag>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$UPDATE_FLAG"/>
                    </UpdateRequiredFlag>
            </customerData>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I am able to get the UpdateRequiredFlag inside each iteration and it comes only in one of the iterations. Is there any way I can access that variable from outside the for-each loop? Would be a great help if this is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to access a variable which is declared inside a `for-each` from a point which is outside the `for-each`. The scope of any variable which is declared within a `template` is _only_ the following siblings of the variable's declaration. The hierarchy of XML elements in the stylesheet strictly defines the visibility of variable assignments ("bindings"). You need to compute the value of `$UPDATE_FLAG` right where you need to use it, or at a higher level in the hierarchy (i.e. the `variable` should be a child of an ancestor element of where the variable is used)

Comment: variables in xslt are immutable. Im struggling to work out what the code is trying to do, if you want to have a boolean var that searches for some condition you would usually use a variable and an XPATH select that selects items that matches the condition.

Comment: XSLT doesn't work this way, and it's difficult to reverse engineer your requirement from code that takes a completely wrong approach. Start again, describing the problem you want to solve (input and output XML) rather than your incorrect attempt to solve it.